# File containing columns from different files Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, file-handling

I want to combine multiple columns from 2 files.

First File ex:

```
Name   Age
Bob    22
Carl   19
Daniel 29
Frank  31
Zach   22
```

Second File ex: (THERE IS NO GPA VALUE FOR DANIEL SO WE LEAVE IT EMPTY)

```
Name   GPA
Bob    3.0
Carl   3.5
Daniel
Frank  2.6
Zach   2.9
```

I want to ouput something that looks like

```
Name   Age    GPA
Bob    22     3.0
Carl   19     3.5
Daniel 29
Frank  31     2.6
Zach   22     2.9
```

Since the names are the same, I can use the first column of either file.

Here is the code I have so far, but it's not outputting anything.

```
unless (open COL1, '<'. $file1) {die "Couldn't open '$file1'\n";}
unless (open COL2, '<'. $file2) {die "Couldn't open '$file2'\n";}

my %feature;
my @files = (scalar <COL1>, scalar <COL2>);

for my $file (@files) {
    open my $infh, '<', $file or die $!;
    while (<$infh>) {
        chomp;
        my ($feature, $value) = split /\s+/, $_;
        push @{$feature{$feature}}, $value;
    }
}
close COL1;
close COL2;
foreach my $k (keys %feature) {
    print "$k @{$feature{$k}}\n";
}
```

How can I fix this so that it takes the first and second column from the first file and appends the second column from the second file onto it? (I want it in the order of Name, Age, GPA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use List::Util qw( max );

my %students;

{
    open(my $fh, '<', $qfn1)
       or die("Can't open \"$qfn1\": $!\n");
    while (<$fh>) {
        my ($name, $age) = split;
        $students{$name}{age} = $age;
    }
}

{
    open(my $fh, '<', $qfn2)
       or die("Can't open \"$qfn2\": $!\n");
    while (<$fh>) {
        my ($name, $gpa) = split;
        $students{$name}{gpa} = $gpa;
    }
}

my $max_name_len = max map length, "Name", keys %students;
my $max_age_len  = max map length, "Age", grep defined, map $_->{age}, values %students;
my $max_gpa_len  = max map length, "GPA", grep defined, map $_->{gpa}, values %students;

printf("%-*s %-*s %-*s\n",
    $max_name_len, "Name",
    $max_age_len,  "Age",
    $max_gpa_len,  "GPA",
);

for my $name (sort keys %students) {
    my $student = $students{$name};
    my $age = $student->{age};
    my $gpa = $student->{gpa};
    printf("%-*s %*s %*s\n",
        $max_name_len, $name,
        $max_age_len,  $age // "",
        $max_gpa_len,  $gpa // "",
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The actual file doesn't contain the headers (name, age, gpa). Is there anyway to identify the column by its position? Because if I were to add in new names and info, the top of the list will vary and I don't want to have to go in to manually change it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code I posted is identifying the columns by position (as opposed to by name, which you just said isn't available anyway).

Comment: I got a bit confused and now I see that you do a printf to actually write out the column name. The code works great, as expected!! :)

Comment: Question about this. I'm having a bit of trouble understand why max is used here with map length? Is that just telling it to attribute the column name to the top of the column  in the output?

Comment: We need to know how large to make the columns. `max map length, "Name", keys %students` gets the keys (the names), finds the length of each one and of the string `Name` by passing them to `map length,`, then passes these lengths to `max` to find the largest one.

Answer (score 1):

Much as I like perl... non-perl shell one-liner:

```
$ join --header -t $'\t' file1.txt file2.txt
Name    Age     GPA
Bob     22      3.0
Carl    19      3.5
Daniel  29
Frank   31      2.6
Zach    22      2.9
```

(Does require bash, zsh, or another shell that understands `$'\t'` literals, as well as GNU join. Also assumes the files are sorted like your example.)

Comment: I use csh and I don't think that join is recognized (as far as I'm aware).

Comment: @sfr It's a posix utility (the `--header` option is a gnu extension though... But I see you said in a different comment that the header lines aren't in your real data so it's not even needed. Standard `join` will work fine.)